# RxJava capture network response code when there is no reponse body

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

Trying to get up to speed with RxJava. I have a network call that returns no data. The only response is the code (happy path: 200, 4xx otherwise). I want to listen for this response, but all I can find is how to do it with some sort of response object.

```
@GET
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> makeHttpCall(@Url String url);
```

So my RxJava code looks like this:

```
myRetrofit.makeHttpCall(url)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Timber.d("on completed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            if (!(e instanceof EOFException)) {
                Timber.e(e, "error occurred");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
            Timber.d("on next");
        }
    });
```

This works, but it seems like the wrong solution. I don't like how my observer drops into the onError method. My response is a 200, so I'd like to see it in the onNext or onCompleted methods.

I looked into using Completable, but that didn't work at all. I still think that might be the right way to go, however.

What is the best approach here? I'm wondering if the issue simply traces to my use of `<Response<ResponseBody>>` and whether there is a different type that is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only care about the Http code response then something like this should surfice :

Api:

```
@GET
Single<Response<ResponseBody>> makeHttpCall(@Url String url);
```

Call:

```
myRetrofit.makeHttpCall(url)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .map(Response::code)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(
                            i -> Timber.d("code " + i),
                            e -> {
                                if (!(e instanceof EOFException)) {
                                    Timber.e(e, "error occurred");
                                }
                            });
```

Also note in your original code you pass the `Response<ResponseBody>` to the `Observer` on the main thread - interacting with the `ResponseBody` on this thread will cause a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` as dealing with the body is considered a IO operation - I know not your desired intention here, but worth noting when you make api calls that require interaction with the body.

Comment: Thanks. I really don't think that this solution improves on my own. Maybe I should have been more specific (and will edit my op accordingly). I'm hoping to find something so that I get into the onNext or onCompleted rather than onError methods. That's where I think my solution is kind of hacky.

Comment: @Alex I think you want `onErrorReturn()` or `onErrorResumeNext()` if you never want `onError()` to be called, or use a `filter` in your chain to only allow response code 200's. I agree your original question (and title) are misleading as there are many ways you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribe(rx.functions.Action1,%20rx.functions.Action1,%20rx.functions.Action0)

> Subscription  subscribe(Action1 onNext,
>   Action1 onError, Action0 onCompleted)
>   Subscribes to an Observable and provides callbacks to handle the items it emits and any error or completion notification it issues.

```
myRetrofit.makeHttpCall(url)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(n->Timber.d("on next"), e->{
            if (!(e instanceof EOFException)) {
                Timber.e(e, "error occurred");
            }
     }, ()->Timber.d("on completed"));
```